# Perl hash strict ref error in spreadsheet

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, strict, refs

Below is the perl code

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook = new Spreadsheet::WriteExcel( 'one_worksheet.csv' );

my ${path_1} = $workbook->add_worksheet('Max Input');
my ${path_2} = $workbook->add_worksheet('Min Input');

foreach (keys %max_hash ) {
    ${$_}->write(0, $column, "$max_hash{$_}" );
    $column = $column + 1;
}
```

I get this error

```
"Can't use string ("path_1") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use".
```

`%max_hash` has the keys `path_1` and `path_2`.

What is the solution?

Comment: Could you try to [format the code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?

Comment: Personal suggestion, perhaps have a look at `Excel::Writer::XLSX` if that would fit your requirements, it has really nice documentation as well. Im not implying that would be a solution, I just saw it as a simpler excel writer :)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `my ${path_1}` is unusual, but not actually a problem. With `use warnings` turned on, you'll get a warning message:

> Ambiguous use of ${path_1} resolved to $path_1

Best to just replace it with `my $path_1`.

Your actual problem is this line:

```
${$_}->write(0,$column,"$max_hash{$_}");
```

You're trying to use something called "symbolic references" (also know as "using a variable as the name of a variable"). And they are a very bad idea for [all](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) [sorts](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) of [reasons](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html) - which is why `use strict` prevents you from doing it.

Far better to store your worksheets in a hash.

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# "Class->new()" is far better than "new Class"
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->( 'one_worksheet.csv' );
my %worksheets;
$worksheets{path_1} = $workbook->add_worksheet('Max Input');
$worksheets{path_2} = $workbook->add_worksheet('Min Input');
foreach(keys %max_hash) {
    $worksheets{$_}->write(0, $column, $max_hash{$_});
    $column = $column + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use curly braces when declaring variables. Use:

```
my $path_1 = $workbook->add_worksheet('Max Input');
```

`${something}` syntax means dereference, so perl treats `something` as a reference. Besides, it's wrong to use it with `my`.

Comment: Okay. Then how to initialize a scalar that has "_" in it. If say print  $path_1, will it not look for $path variable instead of $path_1 ?

Comment: In Perl, `_` can be part of variable. So if you create `$path_1` variable, your variable will be named `$path_1` and `print $path_1` will print `$path_1` content. `_` itself has no special meaning in Perl.

Comment: *You can't use curly braces when declaring variables* - That's not true. It's a pretty pointless thing to do, but nothing stops you doing it.

Comment: @DaveCross, you're right, I'll try to rephrase my answer.